# Deriving the formula for an interest related problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I spent a while yesterday trying to find a formula that could answer this problem:

lets say you owe $80,000 on a loan.

Every year you pay back 10% of what you owe after subtracting what you paid already from the principal of $80,000.

So year 1, you pay $(80,000 x 0.1) = 8000$,

year 2 you pay $(80,000 - 8000) x 0.1 = 7200$,

year 3 you pay $(80,000 - 8000 - 7200) x 0.1 = 6480$,

I tried to substitute x and b for 80,000 and 0.1, and write out what each year would look like as an expression.

$year 1 = xb$
$year 2 = (x-xb)b$
$year 3 = (x-xb-(x-xb)b)b$

Year four gets really long and I made a mistake in distributing.  Anyway I did not see a pattern in the expressions.

My question is how to approach coming up with a formula that can tell you the total principal paid based on n years passing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

There is a *much* easier way of doing this.

If you pay back $xb$ after the first year, how much is left to pay? $x-xb$, as you say. But you can factorise this to $x(1-b)$. Now, the second year, you say you pay $(x-xb)b$. But using the factorised form, this is $x(1-b)b$. Doesn't seem much simpler, until you try to find how much you have left to pay after this second payment to work out how much the third payment is. You started year 2 owing $x(1-b)\cdot 1$, you paid $x(1-b)\cdot b$, so you must have $x(1-b)(1-b) = x(1-b)^{2}$ left to pay after year 2, so year 3 you pay $x(1-b)^{2}\cdot b$. Can you see the pattern?

The rule is that, since you pay $b$ times whatever you still owe at each payment, after each payment, you will still owe $(1-b)$ times what you owed before the payment. So the amount still owed after $n$ payments is $x(1-b)^{n}$, which is a nice simple expression. You can use this to find the total amount you've paid, which is the principal minus the amount you still owe, and hence $x\left[1-(1-b)^{n}\right]$.

Comment: Nice answer.  I wonder if you could share you're approach to coming up with the idea to factorize in the beginning, which seems to make it easier to spot the pattern.

Comment: To be honest, I just always learned to do it this way. You're always paying off the same percentage of the remaining amount, so the remaining amount will always get multiplied by the same factor - 90% in this case, or $1-b$ in general. If you can find some property like this that is nice and regular, it will make things much easier.